# How can I specify a const list of of keys, and derive a Picked interface from that list, in a type-safe way?

Tags: typescript

I have a predefined and complex interface which I cannot manipulate since it comes from a third party library.

```
interface Fruit {
    name?: string;
    id?: number;
    weight?: number;
}
```

I need to

- Define a list of a subset of the keys of that interface, and then
- Define a new interface (or type) which will have just those^ members, which will be typed the same as the original interface.

To clarify: I need to actually use the list in my code (otherwise I would just write them into a `Pick<Fruit, ...>` and be done with it).

Here is one approach:

```
const fieldsToIsolate = ["id", "weight"] as const;

type IsolatedFruit = Pick<Fruit, typeof fieldsToIsolate[number]>;
// type IsolatedFruit = {
//     id?: number | undefined;
//     weight?: number | undefined;
// }
```

The problem with this approach is that `fieldsToIsolate` is not type-safe.

Here is a different approach which solves that, but has its own problem:

```
const fieldsToIsolate: Array<keyof Fruit> = ["id", "weight"];

type IsolatedFruit = Pick<Fruit, typeof fieldsToIsolate[number]>;
// type IsolatedFruit = {
//     name?: string | undefined;
//     id?: number | undefined;
//     weight?: number | undefined;
// }
```

Now the list is safely typed, but `IsolatedFruit` is not accurate.

Typescript now complains if we try to re-attach `as const`, because

```bash
The type 'readonly ["id", "weight"]' is 'readonly' and cannot be assigned to the mutable type '(keyof Fruit)[]'
```

Is there a way to achieve this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would do this with the `satisfies` keyword, which was introduced in [typescript 4.9](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/release-notes/typescript-4-9.html):

```
const fieldsToIsolate = ["id", "weight"] satisfies Array<keyof Fruit>;

type IsolatedFruit = Pick<Fruit, typeof fieldsToIsolate[number]>;
```

This causes typescript to do 2 things:

1. `fieldsToIsolate` will get a more specific type than `string[]`, based on the exact values you used. In this example, the type will be `('id' | 'weight')[]`. This in turn allows `IsolatedFruit` to be the correct type.
2. Typescript will check to verify that "id" and "weight" are indeed keys of `Fruit` and will give an error if they are not. So typos and nonexistent keys will be brought to your attention.

[Playground link](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/JYOwLgpgTgZghgYwgAgGJQK7DMg3gKGSORDgFsIB%20ALmQGcwpQBzAbkOOABMaSMyARtHbFkAdwjBmACzC8Q-IVHYBffPgQB7EA2QxgEADZc6AFU0BJOpsNxIyALzIA2gCJurgDTJXEqbNcAXXo7YDp9CDpkAEEoKDgATwAeAGsIBM0YNExsAD52LR0cATguVANjKKc3D29fGTAgkLAwiKjY%20OS0jKz0LDBc9TAEgAcUKxs7CDKcnCcABWAEFKS%207G9hscy9CpNzCdtIZwVBaED8oA)